# Casting return from ClassUtil.newInstance

Tags: java, secure-coding

I started getting into java security and had a question I could not find an answer to.

Lets say we have a web application that uses the following code, and that the UserControlledString can be set to be whatever class we want:

```
SomeClass someClassObj = (SomeClass) ClassUtil.newInstance(UserControlledString);
```

Would it be possible to exploit this and cause harm? From what I can tell most likely not but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `ClassUtil` is, but for `Class.newInstance`:

- Some classes self-register from their constructor. A terrible idea,
  but there you go. The instance will therefore persist even if it is
  not an instance of `SomeClass`.
- Perhaps there really is a subtype of `SomeClass` hanging that is
  inappropriate.
- The `ClassLoader` may perform relatively expensive network or file
  access, and may accrete memory that wont go away until the process is
  rebooted.
- It opens up the attack surface through badly written `ClassLoader`s.
  Think of all the fun characters you could put in the string.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the self registering class example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what some class is and what you are doing with it. In an of itself, there is nothing inherently insecure about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to cause harm if `SomeClass` is a parent class and the `UserControlledString` is the child class

Take parent class `Discount` as an example. There are child classes `MixAndMatchDiscount` and `QuantityDiscount`.

`Discount discountObj = (Discount) ClassUtil.newInstance(UserControlledDiscountString);`

Users can modify the expected discount to another discount to get a better price in case they know your class name.